# Cannot receive JMS messages from external Artemis servers with Camel route using JMS component for parameter concurrentConsumers more than one

Tags: java, jboss, apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

A Camel route setup in JBoss EAP 7.4.2 that tries to concurrently receive JMS messages from external ActiveMQ Artemis servers fails with following warning.

```
2023-xx-xx 16:04:37,066 GMT WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] (Camel (StandardContext) thread #12 - JmsConsumer[XXXQueue]) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'XXXQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: Only allowed one session per connection. See the J2EE spec, e.g. J2EE1.4 Section 6.6
```

**Camel route:**

```java
from("jms:queue:XXX?concurrentConsumers=2") // or more
    .process("xyz")
    .end();
```

**Environment:**

**JBoss EAP 7.4.2** receiving JMS messages from three external **ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16** servers with support for failovers/HA using default protocol, using **Apache Camel 2.25.4**.

**ActiveMQ Artemis resource adapter settings:**

```xml
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
        <remote-connector name="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-1" socket-binding="artemis-sharedinternal-1"/>
        <remote-connector name="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-2" socket-binding="artemis-sharedinternal-2"/>
        <remote-connector name="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-3" socket-binding="artemis-sharedinternal-3"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="org.apache.activemq" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-1 netty-artemis-sharedinternal-2 netty-artemis-sharedinternal-3" ha="true" failover-on-initial-connection="true" use-topology-for-load-balancing="true" transaction="none" user="user" password="password" min-pool-size="24" use-auto-recovery="true" max-pool-size="256" initial-connect-attempts="2" statistics-enabled="true" enable-amq1-prefix="false">
            <inbound-config use-jndi="false" rebalance-connections="true" setup-attempts="2" setup-interval="5000"/>
        </pooled-connection-factory>
        ...
```

**Queries:**

1. Is there a work around to avoid warning/failure?
2. Is it possible to create a non JCA compliant Artemis connection factory in JBoss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camel component you're using was written for a "normal" JMS `ConnectionFactory`. However, you're using a JCA-based `ConnectionFactory` from `pooled-connection-factory`.

The way to avoid the warning is to use a `connection-factory` rather than a `pooled-connection-factory`. Here's an example based on what you already have configured:

```xml
<connection-factory name="org.apache.activemq" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="netty-artemis-sharedinternal-1 netty-artemis-sharedinternal-2 netty-artemis-sharedinternal-3" ha="true" failover-on-initial-connection="true" use-topology-for-load-balancing="true" enable-amq1-prefix="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I will give this a try and then confirm the solution on this page. It may take a few days though

Comment: Hi Justin. I need a quick confirmation about setting user and password attributes for connection-factory. Should these be entered as shown below.
    `<cluster user="user" password="password"/>`
as a subelement in `<subsystem>`

Comment: The `<cluster user="user" password="password"/>` is for _clustering_. It's not for JMS connection factories. The code that looks up `java:/ConnectionFactory` should use the appropriate username and password when it invokes [`createConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html#createConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [`createContext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html#createContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Works. Using a pooled connection factory for the JBoss message handling code and a "normal" connection factory for Camel JMS components. Now the concurrentConsumers can be set (>= 1). Had to set the userid/password using Camel JMS component API. Also had to remove 3 attributes from the pooled-connection factory: `failover-on-initial-connection`, `transaction` and `use-auto-recovery` as otherwise messages not received by JMS component. Also had to add `<external-jms-queue name="XXXQueue" entries="queue/XXXQueue"/>` for all queues that receive messages using Camel JMS component.

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the number of JMS connections that a "normal" connection-factory can provide?

Comment: A `ConnectionFactory` is just a factory object. There is no limit on the number of connections it can provide.

Comment: Hi Justin. Please provide some insight into the other issues/items that needed changes, namely the need to remove attributes from `pooled-connection-factory` and the need for `<external-jms-queue name="XXXQueue" entries="queue/XXXQueue"/>` for all queues that are used by Camel JMS component to receive messages. I thought there was a stack overflow discussion on this issue earlier (possibly a comment), but cannot find it. Thx

Comment: I believe we're getting somewhat off-topic from the original question at this point. I believe I've addressed your original question so If you have additional questions please create new questions for them. Stack Overflow is not really a _discussion_ platform but rather a _question & answer_ platform. A good question is clear and concise and can be addressed with a fact-based answer. Questions that elicit opinion-based answers and extended discussion in the comments section are discouraged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255190/discussion-between-surjit-sen-and-justin-bertram).

Comment: Hi Justin. Point well taken. Will create new question with additional details. It may be important for other readers